# Spawn a job with higher priority in Jenkins if there are already jobs in the queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's assume that with Jenkins, I have a queue that is piled up with 10 jobs waiting for execution. 
One of the executing jobs has failed, and I managed to fix the issue, and push the change. 
I know that nobody will be able to push  their work, until all job types in build radiator are "green". 
Therefore I would like the ability to bypass the jobs in the queue so the failed job will run again.

I saw the following plugin - [Priority sorter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) - but I'm not sure that I can use this for the above scenario : 
Let's say I configure all jobs to run with priority 50, and then I re-configure the failed job to run with priority one, will it bypass all the jobs in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to that functionality would be the [Accelerated Build Now Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin).

> [The plugin] allows Jenkins users to launch a project's build right away, even if the queue is long (**moving it to the top of the queue**) and even if no executor is available (killing and rescheduling builds not launched by "humans")

Comment: Cant find any groovy syntax (of mentioned plugin) to do so?